# pgr_dijkstra return empty result

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, dijkstra, pgrouting

I want to use pgr_dijkstra in postgresql for OSM data.
Steps :

1. Insert OSM data into table 'streets' that contains source and target columns.
2. Create streets_noded table with pgr_nodenetwork function.
3. Use streets table in pgr_dijkstra.

Why the result is null ? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I followed the steps of [this link](https://github.com/planetfederal/workshops/blob/master/tutorials/osm-routing/src/index.rst) and It's worked!